# SQLite returns no such column error in attribute name when name typed but works when copied from create statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, character-encoding

I have an SQL query in SQLite that includes column names with underscore `_` characters. I have trouble when I type the column name (`Nom_ligne`) into the query (I get `SQL error: no such column`). I have been able to get my query to work when I copy-paste the column name directly into the query after using `PRAGMA table_info`. They look identical to me but Notepad++ does not recognize the column name as identical (it highlights all occurrences of the same set of characters when you click on a set of character).

I have [found](https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=UNDERSCORE) that there are two different kinds of underscore characters that look identical. How can I choose to type the correct one? Is that the problem with my lines of code (see below)?

[image]

Here my lines of code with the different characters.

```
> #this works 
SELECT train_arret.stop_name FROM train_arret_ligne, lignes_train, train_arret WHERE
train_arret.stop_code_=train_arret_ligne.ID_arret AND
train_arret_ligne.ligne_code=lignes_train.ID_ligne AND
lignes_train.Nom_ligne="Candiac"
> 
##returns error SQL error: "no such column: lignes_train.Nom_ligne" 
SELECT train_arret.stop_name FROM train_arret_ligne, lignes_train,
train_arret WHERE train_arret.stop_code_=train_arret_ligne.ID_arret
AND train_arret_ligne.ligne_code=lignes_train.ID_ligne AND
lignes_train.Nom_ligne="Candiac"
> 
> #these work 
SELECT lignes_train.ID_ligne FROM lignes_train WHERE             
lignes_train.Nom_ligne="Candiac"
```

EDIT:

I typed this from scratch (no copy-paste) and I get an error.

```
SELECT train_arret.stop_name FROM train_arret_ligne, lignes_train, train_arret
WHERE train_arret.stop_code_=train_arret_ligne.ID_arret AND
train_arret_ligne.ligne_code=lignes_train.ID_ligne AND
lignes_train.Nom_ligne="Candiac"
```

MORE EDITS:

When I copy lines of the code through the hex editor`FlexHEX`, I find that the extra hidden character `EF BB BF` is necessary to get the code to work in the SQL query. I also can detect the extra character in SQLITE/SPATIALLITE when I move over the text. It shows up as the following in `FlexHEX`:

```
#doesn't work
lignes_train.ID_ligne 
#works
lignes_train.ï»¿ID_ligne
```

Here is what I get when I ask SQLITE/SPATIALLITE to show me the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE "lignes_train" (
"PK_UID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"ID_ligne" INTEGER,
"Nom_ligne" TEXT)
```

Comment: Your first two queries are identical, except for newlines and maybe spacing.  So, my guess is that this is just some sort of typo problem.

Comment: carthesians joins are deprecated since about 25 years. Consider using `JOIN` keyword. Beside that, as said @TimBiegeleisen this might be hidden characters. Try changing encoding in np++

Comment: @Cid And yet they still persist far often than you might guess, e.g. at my last job, where I got into trouble for suggesting that someone do it the modern way :-(

Comment: There is one hidden character between `lignes_train.` and `Nom_ligne`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen a manager suggested me once to store each users in its own database (yes, the entries that contains username and stuff), because *"that would be easier to maintain to create a database per user"*

Comment: Specifically, copy and pasting that into a hex editor shows the bytes `EF BB BF` in that spot.

Comment: The keyboard will generate a U+005f.  If the table were created with a column name using U+0332, you will have to substitute that character whenever you type type the column name (e.g., by cut and paste).  If the column name was created with U+0332, consider changing it.

Comment: @rd_nielsen My column names were created by me typing them in. Could it be a question of keyboards? I usually use `CAFR` (Canadian French Keyboard) but sometimes windows automatically changes it to `US keyboard`.  So it is possible that I changed keyboards in between

Comment: @user3386170 - More likely your editor than keyboard.  If you used something like MS-Word that 'helpfully' substitutes special characters for ASCII characters, you could have gotten the underscore replaced without actually recognizing it.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the underscore character. It's the garbage bytes between `lignes_train.` and `Nom_ligne` that Cid pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking one of the column names that doesn't produce an error:

```
$ echo 'lignes_train.Nom_ligne' | xxd
00000000: 6c69 676e 6573 5f74 7261 696e 2e4e 6f6d  lignes_train.Nom
00000010: 5f6c 6967 6e65 0a                        _ligne
```

The column name that does produce an error:

```
$ echo 'lignes_train.<feff>Nom_ligne' | xxd
00000000: 6c69 676e 6573 5f74 7261 696e 2eef bbbf  lignes_train....
00000010: 4e6f 6d5f 6c69 676e 650a                 Nom_ligne.
```

As you can see, for some reason there are three extra bytes, `EF BB BF` between the period and the column name. Those bytes aren't a valid UTF-8 encoded character, hence showing up as `<feff>` in my shell. I have no idea why your editor isn't doing something similar (Assuming you're telling it to use UTF-8 for that buffer, which, since it's the default text encoding used by sqlite, you really should be... I'm also surprised that SO doesn't indicate them). That's the cause of the error. The underscore character, `U+005F` is the same in both.

Credit should go to @Cid for finding it.

Comment: What's a hex editor? I tried using npp to show all characters and I did see a `?` in my original code sample that I had posted. However, I tried typing the code from scratch directly in `sqlite`, which produced an error, but when I pasted it in npp I didn't see any characters show up (see edit in question).

Comment: @user3386170 A hex editor is a program that displays the raw bytes of its input (Usually in base 16, hence 'hex') instead of trying to interpret it as a particular format. Important part of any programmer's debugging toolkit. -- What's the error in your new statement?-- That question mark was Notepad++ pointing out that something was funky with the text.

Comment: same type of error. `SQL error: no such column lignes_train.ID_lignes`

Comment: @user3386170 If there's any unusual bytes in that they didn't survive copy and pasting into SO. I see it's for a *different* column name, so... does that one exist? You should probably add your table definitions (As text, **not** a screenshot image) to your question.

Comment: It's the code with an extra random character that works!  I am so confused. I will add more to my question (and then trim it down significantly once it is figured out...).

Comment: It seems that the column name `ID_lignes` had an extra character in it at the very beginning. I had imported the table from a csv that I might have created in QGIS using sql queries or I might have modified from a text file (I'm still figuring out my way around sql so I'm trying different things out and not being systematic every time about writing it down).

Comment: I re-imported the table from the .csv file and the attribute name came out with the extra character again so I think there is either a problem with importing from .csv or the .csv got corrupted at some point.

Comment: My (budding) programming skills have improved leaps and bounds! I had no idea that there could be hidden characters that caused problems... and no idea about hex editors.

Comment: I re-imported the table from the .csv file and the attribute name came out with the extra character again. I had saved the .csv file as `csv UTF-8 (comma-delimited)`. When I retried saving as `csv (comma-delimited)`, the attribute names imported correctly without extra symbol in front of the first column name. I also found that the extra symbol appeared in `R` when I imported the file so it is something in the file format that imports incorrectly in other platforms (but QGIS seems to be able to support the csv UTF-8 format without odd column names in its `query builder`)